# Retrieve data from dataset webservice in Xamarin and set it to textview

Tags: android, xamarin, dataset

Here is my code. Im getting the data but name1 return's null value. I want to display the data obtain from the webservice in form of dataset in textView and imageview. Can you help me please?

When it executes line  `name1.SetText(productName);`
the error get is

Unhandled Exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. occurred

below is what the local variable stored.

> Name  Value Type
>
> detailOfproduct         "The botle is"            string
>
> fdetail                 "The botle is"            string
>
> fimage                  "iVBORw0"                 string
>
> fname                   "Bottle"                  string
>
> imageproduct            "iVBORw0"                 string
>
> productName             "Bottle"                  string
>
> name1                   (null)
>   Android.Widget.TextView
>
> detail                  (null)
>   Android.Widget.TextView

```
WebReferencec.WebService add = new WebReferencec.WebService();
DataSet result = add.getData("bottle");

DataTable dt = result.Tables["product"];


        //DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

       fname = dt.Rows[0]["name"];            
       fdetail= dt.Rows[0]["detail"];
       fimage = dt.Rows[0]["image"];

       // dt.Rows.Add(row);


         imageproduct = Convert.ToString(fimage);
         productName = Convert.ToString(fname);
         detailOfproduct = Convert.ToString(fdetail);

        byte[] ba = Convert.FromBase64String(imageproduct);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(ba))
        {
            ImageView image = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ivgallery);
            TextView name1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvname);
            TextView detail = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvdetail);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(ba, 0, ba.Length);
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                image.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
                name1.SetTextKeepState( productName);
                detail.SetTextKeepState( detailOfproduct);

                }
            );

        }
```

Comment: Did you call `SetContentView` prior to this? If so, does this layout contain those views you are trying to find? Where your code called?

Comment: Yes but i did solve the problem. Instead of imageview image i put var image. Instead of textview name i put var name... same for detail

Comment: That shouldn't change anything. Sounds like a rebuild would solve this issue as to Resources not being generated...

Comment: it It does make a difference as textview is an object where as var string. I did tried to build it and run it another project and laptop!! it did not worked. but worked well with the var

Answer (score 0):

When i declared the variable image name and detail by puting imageview and text view the variable are not in string. So i had to put var infront to convert it to string.

Var image = FindViewById(Resource.Id.ivgallery);

Var name1 = FindViewById(Resource.Id.tvname);

var detail = FindViewById(Resource.Id.tvdetail);